# What is the Molecular Formula for CH3-C≡C-CH2-CH3

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am taking an Organic Chemistry class in my college and I was wondering what the Molecular Formula for CH3-C≡C-CH2-CH3 was.

It would also be nice to have the class of compound.

Comment: Seems like 2-Pentene http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentene

Comment: @RyanArmstrong, 2-pentene is not the correct name for this compound. The triple-bond makes it an alkyne, not an alkene. Jerry has correctly identified the compound in his answer below as 2-pentyne/pent-2-yne.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you didn't mean the name of this molecule? Because strictly speaking, the molecular formula of the molecule you posted would be $\ce{C5H8}$. Pent-2-ene has molecular formula $\ce{C5H10}$.

The molecule you asked about has a triple bond, meaning that it's an **alkyne** and in this case, pent-2-yne. If you want the wiki page, it's [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Pentyne).

Count the number of carbon atoms and the number of hydrogen atoms to be sure.